# How to recognize unknown patterns in data frame by row?

Tags: r, dataframe, design-patterns, row, analysis

I have a data frame where I have agricultural use codes (1-5) for 15 consecutive years. Each row is a polygon representing a field. Ultimately I need R to loop through the rows and recognize patterns of use and tell me their respective frequency. Unfortunately in my real data set I have over 1 mio. features and thus all possible patterns are not known.

```
a <- data.frame(replicate(15, sample(0:5,500,rep=TRUE)))
colnames(a) <- paste0("use",2005:2019)
id <- c(1:500)
a <- cbind(id,a)

id use2005 use2006 use2007 use2008 use2009 use2010 use2011 use2012 use2013 use2014 use2015 ...
1  1       1       1       1       1       2       2       1       4       4       4       ...
2  4       4       4       4       5       5       5       0       5       5       5       ...
3  1       4       3       2       3       2       4       5       1       1       1       ...
4  1       1       1       1       1       2       2       1       4       4       4       ...
5  4       2       2       2       2       5       3       3       3       3       3       ...
```

So in this arbitrary example, the code should recognize that id 1 & 4 have the same pattern.

In the end I imagine the result to be some sort of frequency distribution to see if there are certain patterns in the agricultural use of my fields.

For example:

1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 2 4 1 1 1

[50] - occurs 50 times

5 5 5 5 5 1 1 1 1 4 4 4 2 2 3

[35] - occurs 35 times

and so forth with all existing combinations...

Unfortunately I have no idea how to approach this. I have no experience with pattern recognition.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this?

```
library(tidyverse)
a[, -1] %>% group_by_all %>% count
#  use2005 use2006 use2007 use2008 use2009 use2010 use2011 use2012 use2013 use2014 use2015     n
#     <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int> <int>
# 1       1       1       1       1       1       2       2       1       4       4       4     2
# 2       1       4       3       2       3       2       4       5       1       1       1     1
# 3       4       2       2       2       2       5       3       3       3       3       3     1
# 4       4       4       4       4       5       5       5       0       5       5       5     1
```

or if you want to include fields you could change to `group_by_at` and exclude `id` from the grouping and then `paste` fields together:

```
a %>%
  group_by_at(vars(-id)) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), ids = paste(id, collapse= "," ))
#   use2005 use2006 use2007 use2008 use2009 use2010 use2011 use2012 use2013 use2014 use2015     n ids  
#     <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int> <int> <chr>
# 1       1       1       1       1       1       2       2       1       4       4       4     2 1,4  
# 2       1       4       3       2       3       2       4       5       1       1       1     1 3    
# 3       4       2       2       2       2       5       3       3       3       3       3     1 5    
# 4       4       4       4       4       5       5       5       0       5       5       5     1 2
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!! Is there a way though to retain the ids of the fields? So I later know which fields have which pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how to approach this, using a small example dataset (i.e. the one you posted).

```
library(tidyverse)

# example dataset
a = read.table(text = "
id use2005 use2006 use2007 use2008 use2009 use2010 use2011 use2012 use2013 use2014 use2015
1  1       1       1       1       1       2       2       1       4       4       4      
2  4       4       4       4       5       5       5       0       5       5       5      
3  1       4       3       2       3       2       4       5       1       1       1      
4  1       1       1       1       1       2       2       1       4       4       4      
5  4       2       2       2       2       5       3       3       3       3       3
", header=T)

a %>%
  group_nest(id) %>%                                           # for each row
  mutate(pattern = map(data, ~paste(.x, collapse = ","))) %>%  # create the pattern as a string
  unnest(pattern) %>%                                          # unnest pattern column
  count(pattern, sort = T)                                     # count patterns

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   pattern                   n
#   <chr>                 <int>
# 1 1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,4,4,4     2
# 2 1,4,3,2,3,2,4,5,1,1,1     1
# 3 4,2,2,2,2,5,3,3,3,3,3     1
# 4 4,4,4,4,5,5,5,0,5,5,5     1
```

Comment: This is great, thank you to you too! Is there a way though to retain the IDs of the fields so I can later know which fields have which pattern? Perhaps an extra column listing the ids?

Comment: Yes, you can create a column with elements (a) vector of IDs, (b) the IDs as a string separated by commas (like the pattern column).

Comment: Can you work out how to do this? Or do you want me to update my answer?